# Speed of "git submodule update --remote --recursive --merge --jobs 8" vs "git pull --recurse-submodule --jobs 8" when there are no changes

Tags: git

On my project with only ~30 flat submodules, `git submodule update --remote --recursive --merge --jobs 8` is a lot slower than `git pull --recurse-submodule --jobs 8` when there are no changes on the remotes (maybe because you already updated/pulled not long ago)

```
$ time git submodule update --remote --recursive --merge --jobs 8
real    0m47,996s
$ time git pull --recurse-submodule --jobs 8
real    0m6,747s
```

Indeed using  GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 you see that the check for changes on the remote happen sequentially for `git submodule update --remote --recursive --merge --jobs 8` but in parallel for `git pull --recurse-submodule --jobs 8` (after the main repo is checked first:

tested with git 2.25.1 and git 2.42.0

Is it possible to do the check of the remote state in parallel with `git submodule update --remote --merge --jobs 8` ? If not, what is the reason ? And so if you don't care about the main repo, does `git pull --recurse-submodule` do the same thing as `git submodule update --remote --merge` and should be used instead for performance ? If there are changes, what happens for submodules which are on the main branch without local commits (fast forward) ? What happens for repo which are on another branch featureXYZ when the main branch has advanced on the remote ? when the featureXYZ branch has advanced on the remote ?